# Multiple dynos on Heroku + socket.io broadcasts

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I seem to be having an issue where socket.io broadcasts in my node.js app on Heroku don't seem to work when I have more than 1 dyno.  As soon as I scale it to 1, it works perfectly.  Is there anything I need to know about this?  Maybe there is a different way to broadcast to all dynos?  Please elt me know if I need to provide more info or code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running on multiple dynos/servers then you have to configure socket.io to use a non-in-memory session store like the `RedisStore`. The socket.io [documentation has details](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO) and there's more discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064826/using-socket-io-and-redis-on-heroku-with-node-js).

Comment: Hmm, it seemed to work before but now I see that it works sporadically - sometimes it just gets queued and I get multiple items back all at once. Do you know if there is anything else that needs to be configured or a different call than client.broadcast.to('some room')?