# Socket.io and multiple Dyno's on Heroku Node.js app. WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, redis, socket.io

I'm building an App deployed to Heroku which uses Websockets.

The websockets connection is working properly when I use only 1 dyno, but when I scale to >1, I get the following errors

> POST
>   http://****.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1412600135378-1&sid=zQzJJ8oPo5p3yiwIAAAC
>   400 (Bad Request) socket.io-1.0.4.js:2
>
> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://****.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=websocket&sid=zQzJJ8oPo5p3yiwIAAAC'
>   failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
>   socket.io-1.0.4.js:2

I am using the Redis adaptor to enable multiple web processes

```
var io = socket.listen(server);
var redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
var redis = require('redis');

var pub = redis.createClient(18049, '[URI]', {auth_pass:"[PASS]"});
var sub = redis.createClient(18049, '[URI]', {detect_buffers: true, auth_pass:"[PASS]"} );

io.adapter( redisAdapter({pubClient: pub, subClient: sub}) );
```

This is working on localhost (which I am using foreman to run, as Heroku does, and I am launching 2 web processes, same as on Heroku).

Before I implemented the redis adaptor I got a web-sockets handshake error, so the adaptor has had some effect. Also it is working occasionally now, I assume when the sockets match the same web dyno.

I have also tried to enable sticky sessions, but then it never works.

```
var sticky = require('sticky-session');
sticky(1, server).listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return process.exit(1);
  }
  console.log('Worker listening on %s', port);
});
```

Comment: I did some more exploration of this problem lately, I discovered that if you specify the port when you visit your .herokuapp.com address (ie. yourapp.herokuapp.com:80) the sockets connection works. Although obviously not a practical solution for production! It helps in staging.

Comment: Remy Sharp looks at this in a blog post https://remysharp.com/2014/11/10/muddling-my-way-through-real-time#server-side

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read through that.

Answer (score 22):

*I'm the Node.js Platform Owner at Heroku.*

WebSockets works on Heroku out-of-the-box across multiple dynos; socket.io (and other realtime libs) use fallbacks to stateless processes like xhr polling that break without session affinity.

To scale up socket.io apps, first follow all the instructions from socket.io:

- http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/

Then, enable session affinity on your app (this is a free feature):

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/session-affinity

Comment: hey, hunter.  do you have any info on the number of concurrent socket.io connections i could expect to handle per dyno?  (ballpark is fine).  thanks.

Comment: This works for me! 
I did what @hunterloftis suggested, I'm using [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) and session affinity in heroku and all works great :)

Comment: @Jonah did you ever end up figuring out the load ballpark? Interested as I have the same problem currently

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest i don't think i did, iirc.  we ended up using pusher

Comment: Hi @hunterloftis I know your post is old but I'm hoping you could answer a quick question. I'm able to get a WebSocket server running using socket.io but can I use Ws library instead? Or does Heroku only support socket io?

Comment: @Nina you can use ws as well. Here's an old test repo with a demo: https://github.com/hunterloftis/websocket-ping

Comment: @hunterloftis Coincidently I just found that repo right before you posted your comment and deploys and runs just fine. Thank you! Another question, why is the WS address different than a socket io address? A socket io address can look like this testapp.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket while a WS address can just look like this ws://testapp.herokuapp.com

Comment: i tried all that but it didn't work using this commit https://github.com/ltfschoen/flappytips/commit/8aaaadc3dbd178969ca2dfd3f4607c035f57dd6d. i followed the instructions that you mentioned https://socket.io/docs/v4/using-multiple-nodes/#using-nodejs-cluster where i allowed credentials on client and server, and applied the example shown to create a Node.js Cluster using @socket.io/sticky. i was using Heroku's Basic paid plan, and enabled Heroku Session Affinity as you mentioned, and ran `heroku ps:scale web=1:Basic; heroku features:enable http-session-affinity; heroku ps:restart; heroku open`

Answer (score 6):

I spent a while trying to make socket.io work in multi-server architecture, first on Heroku and then on Openshift as many suggest.

The only way to make it work on both PAAS is disabling xhr-polling and setting `transports: ['websocket']` on both client and server.

On Openshift, you must explicitly set the port of the server to 8000 (for ws – 8443 for wss on socket.io client initialization, using the *.rhcloud.com server, as explained in this post: http://tamas.io/deploying-a-node-jssocket-io-app-to-openshift/.

Polling strategy doesn't work on Heroku because it does not support sticky sessions (https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io/issues/261), and on Openshift it fails because of this issue: https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io/issues/279, that will hopefully be fixed soon.

So, the only solution I found so far, is disabling polling and use websocket transport only.

In order to do that, with socket.io > 1.0
server-side:

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var socketio = require('socket.io')(server, {
  path: '/socket.io-client'
});
socketio.set('transports', ['websocket']);
```

client-side:

```
var ioSocket = io('<your-openshift-app>.rhcloud.com:8000' || '<your-heroku-app>.herokuapp.com', {
    path: '/socket.io-client'
    transports: ['websocket']
})
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I've been searching for a solution for the same problem for almost a week, even got in touch with Heroku support team, but nothing's have been solved. I tried what you mentioned here and it finally Worked!. Thank you, @qubird .

Comment: Im using the Redis adapter for SocketIO & was getting the handshake error. Specifying the websocket transport was the solution. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It could be you need to be running RedisStore:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore(options),
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```

per earlier q here: [Multiple dynos on Heroku + socket.io broadcasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754431/multiple-dynos-on-heroku-socket-io-broadcasts)

Comment: Yup you do need to use the Redis adapter and Redis Store, I already am doing this, but it's still not helping.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't a normal answer, but I've tried to get WebSockets working on Heroku for more than a week. After many long conversations with customer support I finally tried out OpenShift. Heroku WebSockets are in beta, but OpenShift WebSockets are stable. I got my code working on OpenShift in under an hour.

http://www.openshift.com

*I am not affiliated with OpenShift in any way. I'm just a satisfied (non-paying) customer.*

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Glad you got yours fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having huge problems with this. There were a number of issues failing simultaneously making it a huge nightmare. Make sure you do the following to scale socket.io on heroku:

1. if you're using clusters make sure you implement [socketio-sticky-session](https://github.com/wzrdtales/socket-io-sticky-session) or something similar
2. client's connect url should not be `https://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling` but rather `https://example.com/`  notably I'm using https because heroku supports it
3. [enable cors in socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771805/how-to-set-socket-io-origins-to-restrict-connections-to-one-url/21711242#21711242)
4. [specify only websocket connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238628/socket-io-1-x-use-websockets-only)

For you and others it could be any one of these.

if you're having trouble setting up sticky-session clusters here's my working code

```
var http = require('http');
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var sticky = require('socketio-sticky-session');
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
var io;

if(cluster.isMaster){
  console.log('Inside Master');
  // create the worker processes
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs ; i++){
    cluster.fork();
  }
}
else {
  // The worker code to be run is written inside
  // the sticky().
}

sticky(function(){
  // This code runs inside the workers.
  // The sticky-session balances connection between workers based on their ip.
  // So all the requests from the same client would go to the same worker.
  // If multiple browser windows are opened in the same client, all would be
  // redirected to the same worker.
  io = require('socket.io')({transports:'websocket', 'origins' : '*:*'});
  var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.end('socket.io');
  })


  io.listen(server);
  // The Redis server can also be used to store the socket state
  //io.adapter(redis({host:'localhost', port:6379}));

  console.log('Worker: '+cluster.worker.id);
    // when multiple workers are spawned, the client
    // cannot connect to the cloudlet.

    StartConnect(); //this function connects my mongodb, then calls a function with io.on('connection', ..... socket.on('message'...... in relation to the io variable above

    return server;
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 4567, function(){
  console.log('Socket.io server is up ');
});
```

more information:
personally it would work flawlessly from a session not using websockets (I'm using socket.io for a unity game. It worked flawlessly from the editor only!). When connecting through the browser whether chrome or firefox it would show these handshaking errors, along with error 503 and 400.