# My node socket.io connection get automatically disconnect after a short period of inactivity

Tags: node.js, nodes

I have spent a long on Google but I didn't found any solution. I saw many questions related to my problem on stack overflow but I didn't get any solution.
Explaining in brief, I am coding for real time chat room and it works fine when I continuously send messages from either room but when I left it for a short period mean (when message is not send from either side) it automatically gets disconnect inside the browser is still opened. And messages send from one room didn't transferred to other room. Please help me.

```
var express = require('express');  // node code
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var redis = require('redis');
var redis_client = redis.createClient(6379,'192.168.43.49');
redis_client.auth('rajesh');
redis_client.select(1);
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){

  /* used for transfering message from one node to other node */
    socket.on('node_message',function(data){

        // sending message to other end 
        redis_client.smembers(data.user_hash,function(err,reply){

            if(reply!=null){

                reply.forEach(function(value){
                    var res = {'user_hash':socket.user_hash,'msg':data.msg};
                    io.to(value).emit('node_message',res); // i am sending sender user_hash also so that while getting message in second end i will validate second party {cause problem in multi-page to show message in every panel} 
                });

            }

        });

    });
   socket.on('disconnect', function (){
            console.log('lost connection',socket.user_hash);
    })

});
```

Comment: Where's your app deployed to?

Comment: Ah yes, looking at your code I can clearly see the problem with it.

Comment: You should provide code and read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the help center.

Maybe this could help : [socket.io automatically disconnects socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991599/socket-io-automatically-disconnects-socket)

Comment: @NikKyriakidesi have uploaded my node code. I have used redis is node

Comment: @MadWard i have uploaded node code