# RabbitMQ in scalable nodejs Apps, How make a build well scalable app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scalable, single-threaded

What's your opinion about the use of RabbitMQ as messages broker,if I think to do scalable an aplicacion using socket.io into my nodejs project, in comparison with redis wich will be i use??

In which othe scenarios could use Rabbit or there are other tool more powerfull.

what did you recommend me to make a building well scalable aplication in Nodejs.

I'm reading this article 
http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2013/01/31/scaling-real-time-apps-on-cloud-foundry-using-node-js-and-rabbitmq/

I need your Feedback.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Before you start using RabbitMQ, you should try looking into using the nodeJS forking for processes. It has a built-in message queue that will help you see what you need to do.

The built-in messaging queue that's built into node even allows you to pass sockets and http connections, which is pretty great!

Here's the link to forking child processes in the documentation: [NodeJS Documentation: Child Processes](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

And here's a relevant post from before. [Prior StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563401/node-js-multi-threading-and-socket-io)

Try this before you start playing around with RabbitMQ. I tried doing that, and actually came across some difficulty with both implementation and scaling.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that [ZeroMQ](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node) meets your needs.  It requires no separate broker entity.
You will need build tools on your machine because the binding includes a C++ component.